# WebView shows a white page but events are working

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, dom-events

When a webview is done loading it only shows a white page. The strangest part is that events (like a click on an anchor) are still working. After i perform this event and go back (with the back key), the webview is rendered correctly.

This behavior doesn't appear on a HTC Desire with Android 2.3.7, but it appears on the Asus Transformer Prime with Android 4.0.3.

If i put a Thread.sleep(10000) in onPageFinished() the page is visible for 10 seconds but then turns white, events are still working.

The Activity is the Launcher activity and extends a custom base activity. Every activity in my app extends this base activity. The base activity detects if a user is authorized and shows the login activity is needed. When i press the back button after the login activity is displayed, the launcher activity is shows the behavior as described above.

Don't know what to do right now to solve this problem...

The easiest way is to say that it is a bug in Android. But that doesn't solve my problem. Any suggestions to solve this case?

Comment: how can you click on anchore if only white blank page is shown ?

Comment: Thats a good question Ali. Apparently the WebView processes the html right, but doesn't draw it. In fact the webview draw's it for a second, but clears it afterwards. If i add the Thread.sleep(10000) it is visible for 10 seconds.

Comment: may be some java script is creating problems ? some script that runs after the page is loaded ! , try by removing all scripts

Comment: That shouldn't make sense, because the webview works most of the time, but it is worth trying.

Comment: Removing the javascript doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: strange sorry then don't think i can help about this, plz let me know if you found out the solution for this issue

Comment: I changed a little in my startactivity and finish behavior. Now the problem doesn't occur anymore. So it is hard to say what the problem/bug triggers.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for a couple of hours, what solved the problem for me was removing the setting below from my `WebView` constructor call:

```
this.setLongClickable(true);
```

I do not know why this worked.

Comment: It's good to share what worked for you. Even better would be to find out the root cause of the problem.